# Debugging dmesg logs

Tags: centos, rhel, debugging, core-dump

I noticed I have the following in my logs. I just am not sure as to how to go about figuring out how to fix or find out what is causing them and if they are serious.

```
[582046.956291] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 18482 0 0 1379281138 e pipe failed
[582346.769892] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 21093 0 0 1379281439 e pipe failed
[582646.586134] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 23723 0 0 1379281739 e pipe failed
[582946.390029] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 26342 0 0 1379282039 e pipe failed
[583246.202851] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 29010 0 0 1379282340 e pipe failed
[583546.018408] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 31620 0 0 1379282640 e pipe failed
[583845.836688] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 1837 0 0 1379282940 e pipe failed
[584145.645968] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 4416 0 0 1379283241 e pipe failed
[584445.455705] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 7001 0 0 1379283541 e pipe failed
[584745.266532] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 9600 0 0 1379283841 e pipe failed
[585045.074399] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 12209 0 0 1379284141 e pipe failed
[585344.885464] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 14790 0 0 1379284442 e pipe failed
[585644.743818] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 17605 0 0 1379284742 e pipe failed
[585944.511572] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 20183 0 0 1379285042 e pipe failed
[586244.315990] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 22781 0 0 1379285343 e pipe failed
[586544.123020] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 25385 0 0 1379285643 e pipe failed
[586843.932084] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 27984 0 0 1379285943 e pipe failed
[587143.742379] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 30608 0 0 1379286244 e pipe failed
[587443.559349] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 799 0 0 1379286544 e pipe failed
[587743.373027] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 3420 0 0 1379286844 e pipe failed
[588043.175248] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 6031 0 0 1379287145 e pipe failed
[588342.986730] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 8665 0 0 1379287445 e pipe failed
[588642.795951] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 11279 0 0 1379287745 e pipe failed
[588942.608088] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 13915 0 0 1379288045 e pipe failed
[589242.420741] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 16728 0 0 1379288346 e pipe failed
[589542.235065] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 19355 0 0 1379288646 e pipe failed
[589842.061502] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 21998 0 0 1379288946 e pipe failed
[590141.856687] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 24657 0 0 1379289247 e pipe failed
[590441.700335] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 27307 0 0 1379289547 e pipe failed
[590741.483298] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 29944 0 0 1379289847 e pipe failed
[591041.286647] Core dump to |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 7 0 32554 0 0 1379290148 e pipe failed
```

Comment: Try 'abrt-cli list' to see if you can figure out which program is segfaulting - if it's always the same, assume a bug in the program. If there are many different programs segfaulting, assume a hardware issue.

Answer (score 4):

A core dump is generated when a program fails with unexpected results. The above is telling you a command failed and copy of the program that was in memory has handled by the abrt daemon (the command `/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp`). You can then use tools such as `gdb` to debug the failure. Note: gdb is not for the faint-hearted!

Quite often these are the result of poorly written code (it needs to handle exceptions a little better), out of memory issues, or underlying issues such as the command was linked with a certain dynamic load library that has now been changed and the crashing program can no longer use it in the way it expects to.

From [this page](http://binaryjunction.com/2010/07/23/enable-core-dump-files-in-fedora/), there are details on what the Abrt process is, and how it handles cores.

> When “abrtd” is running, the value of sysctl variable “kernel.core_pattern” is different 
>   from the above as shown below:
>
> $sysctl -a|grep core_pattern
>   kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp /var/cache/abrt %p %s %u %c
>
> “abrtd” creates a sub-directory (named something like “ccpp-1279914365-14618″) in the
>   directory “/var/cache/abrt” as shown in the value of the variable. This also means that 
>   the core files will also be stored in that sub-directory in the “/var/cache/abrt” 
>   directory (in addition to the current directory where application was run). ABRT daemon 
>   also creates other files in addition to the core dump files in the sub-directory to 
>   further help users in debugging the crash issue.

Comment: Actually, the core dump hasn't been saved *into* the file `/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp`, but it has been piped to this executable - [RedHat's "Automatic Bug Reporting Tool"](http://linuxwell.com/2012/02/11/core-dumps-in-fedora/). `abrt-cli list` [may display additional information](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-abrt-cli.html#sect-abrt-cli_viewing_problems).

Comment: Add not actually seen this error before, so it was a bit of an assumption :) I'll reflect that in the answer.